# Mongo date displays as null when querying with Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel

In one of my Mongo collections I have  a `startedAt` property on each Document, if I send an AJAX request to get the document directly from Mongo the date comes back as a normal Date object and I can use it as expected, however if I try and query from Laravel, I get a UTCDateTime object that has nothing in it, if I try to print `dd` it I simply get `null` printed.

Below is the query in my controller that I send to Mongo:

```
public function player($accountId)
{
    $skip = 0;
    $take = 10;

    if(isset($_GET['skip'])) $skip = (int)$_GET['skip'];
    if(isset($_GET['take'])) $take = (int)$_GET['take'];

    $matches = Match::where(['players' => array('$elemMatch' => array('accountId' => $accountId))])
        ->skip($skip)
        ->take($take)
        ->get();

    return $matches;
}
```

Every other field in the collection is accessible in blade, but startedAt always returns null.  I've inspected in Mongo Chef and all dates are being saved as `Date` and they are all in a format like: `2016-08-10T00:15:14.251Z`.  Why is Laravel unable to process the mongo date, or am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain but it might be worth having a look at this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

I'm pretty sure this will do the same sort of thing in Mongo and should play nice with blade templates

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed :)